# Meteor lepozepo:s3 with multiple buckets

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I am currently working on an application where I need to be able to upload and delete files.I have finally been able to set up the lepozepo:s3 package to upload and delete files from my AWS bucket and it works well. However, I have 4 buckets in total and the package allows me to configure it for one bucket only. I see that the upload function has options to override the bucket but I can't see any ops for the delete one.

That's how I currently do it:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
    "change .file_bag": function(){
        var files = $("input.file_bag")[0].files

        S3.upload({
            files:files,
            path:"images"
        },function(e,r){
            console.log(r);
        });
    },

    "click button.delete": function(){

        //TODO make more secure by using meteor methods
        S3.delete(this.relative_url, function(e,r){
            console.log(r);
        });

        S3.collection.remove(this._id);
    }

})

Template.postSubmit.helpers({
    "files": function(){
        return S3.collection.find();
    }
})
```

Any suggestions on how to work around that or any options I am not aware of for the package?